# regex_match() && regex_search() infinite loop

Tags: c++, regex

I've written a small function to check a pattern through a regular expression in C++. Using any online regex tester I obtain the behavior I would expect from the regex I've written, but my C++ code ends up in an infinite loop. Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

bool check(const std::string& val, const std::string& sep) {
   const static std::string REGEX_STR("^.{1,}=.{1,}(" + sep + ".{1,})*$");
   const static std::regex REGEX(REGEX_STR);

   std::smatch match;
   //this end up in an infinite loop
   return (std::regex_search(val, match, REGEX) && match.size() > 0);

   //this also end up in an infinite loop
   return std::regex_match(val, REGEX); 
}
```

Can someone explain me why? 
How can I fix this issue?

I'm developing on MS Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Version 14.

Comment: What are the valueus of `val` and `sep`?

Comment: (OT: `+` is short for `{1,}`.)

Comment: replace `^.{1,}=` with `^[^=]{1,}=` or `^[^=]+=` and if it is possible : `.{1,}(` with `[^"+sep+"]+(`. In this way you will avoid a lot of backtracking.

Comment: Second return will never be reached.

Comment: @NathanOliver `val` is the value to be checked and `sep` is a string to be used in the regex like `";"` for example.

Comment: @MatthewRock obviously!!!

Comment: @MatthewRock in a program that manages to execute two consecutive infinite loops there's no such thing as "never".

Comment: @GiovanniLombardo I know what they represent.  I was asking for what is the actual data you are using.  Also if you know the second return will never be reached why do you have it?

Comment: @NathanOliver For illustration purposes.

Comment: @NathanOliver for the purpose of the question it's irrelevant what's the value of val. A valid string could be `"A=A"` an invalid one could be `"AA"`.

Comment: It is a bit strange, I get no issues. So, please describe what input you have. Also consider catastrophic backtracking (see Casimir's suggestion). Something like `^[^=]+=.+(;[^;]+)*$`. Try with `const static std::string REGEX_STR("^[^=]+=[^" + sep + "]+(" + sep + "[^" + sep + "]+)*$");`.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try out my suggestion? Please post sample input and expected output.

Comment: @stribizhev You're right! Using another toolchain, namely MS Visual Studio 2010 V10, all works as expected. Can you explain what you mean with 'backtracking'? What should I do?

Comment: I have tested the code in VS2012, and all seems to work nicely. However, the regex is very poorly written because its adjoining subpatterns may "fall into one another" during backtracking. So, the question is what kind of input you are working with? What are the actual requirements for the input strings (like can there be `=` before `=.+`, or can there be any `sep` after the first `=`... I have re-vamped your regex, but it can be refined further if there were more clear requirements.

Comment: @stribizhev I need to return `true` for strings like `<astring>=<bstring>` && `<astring>=<bstring><sep><cstring><sep><dstring>...` and `false` otherwise. Anyway your re-vamped regex works also in VS2015

Comment: I posted my solution since it worked for you. I also added a link to catastrophic backtracking article on regular-expressions.info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the regex that involves a great amount of backtracking steps to finish. Using `.` (that matches any character but a newline) is not encouraged in case the string is delimited in some way.

I suggest using

```
const static std::string REGEX_STR("^[^=]+=[^" + sep + "]+(" + sep + "[^" + sep + "]+)*$");
```

With `;` passed as separator, it will look like `^[^=]+=[^;]+(;[^;]+)*$` and will parse a string much more efficiently (11 steps) than `^.{1,}=.{1,}(;.{1,})*$` (18 steps). Imagine working with a bigger amount of data, and it will be clear that [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) will happen quicker.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem and lets me understand why my regular expression is inefficient. Remains opened the question whether it's correct an infinite loop or not in VS2015..

Comment: Maybe you can find a clue at [Visual Studio 2015 RTM](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx#C++) Web page...

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking happens due to `.` can match `;` The complexity increases exponentially with respect to number of `;` in the input string.